# IncludePDF inserts PDF But Throws File Not Found Error

Tags: pdfpages

When the following is included in my .tex file:

```
\includepdf[pages={-},fitpaper={true}]{"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf}
```

I receive multiple lines of errors stating

```
Undefined control sequence. ...,fitpaper={true}]{"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf}
Not defining \perthousand.
Not defining \micro.
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
File `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf' not found
\headheight is too small (34.5pt): Make it at least 34.54448pt.
destination with the same identifier (name{page.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.24 \end{document} [2
```

When I remove the line, the document compiles without error.

What am I doing incorrectly!

Comment: Don't use spaces in file names.

Comment: I'm using the grffile package which I think should mean I can use spaces in filenames?

 When I put the line into a seperate tex file and include that tex file it works without problem!?

Comment: I've removed the spaces from my PDF's filename and updated the error causing line to reflect this and the error persists?

Comment: You have only a quote at the start and not at the end.

Comment: Removing the quote doesn't fix the error. Adding that apostrophe where it is seems to make the pdf take up the entire page instead of floating offcentre and off-middle.

Comment: Well without a proper example it is difficult to say what is going wrong. Spaces are a known source for troubles, but your document can have other errors.

Comment: a single quote is definitely wrong, simply not having spaces in the filename is best but "Assignment 1 Brief" probably works,

Comment: the error message indicates, that the file is named `"Assignment 1 Brief.pdf` which is not true accordingly to your example. you named your file `Assignment 1 Brief.pdf`. to make sure your file gets found, encapsulate it inside quotation marks (`"`). also what @David said...

Comment: The `pdfpages` manual explicitly states "The filename *must not* contain any blanks!"

Answer (score 1):

Rename your PDF file `Test.pdf` and place it in the same folder as the TEX file.

If the following code works then `pdfpages` works (in principle) and there is probably another problem (as already discussed in the comments of your question, e. g. spaces in file names or paths or strange `"` characters.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper=true]{Test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

> It is very difficult to help without a proper code example -- this
>   was already mentioned in the comments of your question.